# SQL to find duplicate foreign keys in a group

Tags: sql, postgresql

With tables basically like this:

```
Elements
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
  ...

Observations
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
  ...

Data
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
  observation_id FOREIGN KEY
  element_id FOREIGN KEY
  value FLOAT
  ...
```

I want to find all `observation_id`s where there are duplicate `element_id`s in a single `observation_id`. For example, if I have `Data` records like:

```
1|50|23|4.5
2|50|24|9.9
3|66|23|4.4
4|66|23|4.1
```

Then the query would report `observation_id` `66` because it has two associated rows with `element_id` `23`.

(I'm using PostgreSQL, but this is probably a basic SQL question.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the count() aggregate combined with a 'having' clause:

```
select observation_id, element_id, count(*)
from Data
group by observation_id, element_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks. I was so close.